# JSON API examples in Swagger 2.0

Tags: swagger, json-api, swagger-2.0

I'm trying to create example responses for an endpoint with Swagger 2.0.

```
    200:
      description: Successful response
      schema:
        type: object
        $ref: "#/definitions/User"
      examples:
        application/vnd.api+json:
            - data:
                attributes:
                  full_name: John Appleseed
            - data:
                attributes:
                  full_name: Mike Appleseed
```

My api consumes and produces `application/vnd.api+json`, but it won't recognize it. If I delete the examples, my spec works. Any idea how to specify it?

[image: error]

Comment: This is due to a bug that existed in the JSON Schema used for validation. While it's been fixed, it would take a few days until the editor is updated with it.

Answer (score 9):

It is [not fully implemented yet](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/618), although you can define one single example like this:

```
   responses:
    "200":
      description: Successful response
      schema: 
        $ref: '#/definitions/User'
      examples:
        application/json:
          data:
            id: 1
            attributes:
              attr1: value1
              attr2: value2
```

there is one bug related with the mime-type, you cannot use dots thats why I did not put **application/vnd.api+json**

Comment: Couldn't you use quotes?